# Remove select box value by optgroup

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, optgroup

I have the multiple optgroups in selectbox and its some value are same, I want to remove particular optgroup values. How can i change below code to remove optgroup wise.

```
$("#selectBox option[value='option1']").remove();
```

Comment: how do you knwo which opt group to he removed.. share the html for select and also which group to be removed

Comment: i want to remove only from popular label, please check the below html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case

```
$('#select optgroup[label="popular"] option[value="1"]').remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/snBXu/)